# Exception clears the stack trace of what?

Tags: ruby

I am reading [this blog](http://timeless.judofyr.net/tailin-ruby) and came across following code

```
RunAgain = Class.new(Exception)
def fib(i, n = 1, result = 0)
  if i == -1
    result
  else
    raise RunAgain
  end
rescue RunAgain
  i, n, result = i - 1, n + result, n
  retry
end
```

It seems like for above code to work, once exception is raised then ruby must be clearing the whole stack trace and replacing that with the stack of Exception.

Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this code works actually has nothing to do with the stacktrace. There are two entries on the stack the entire time, `fib` and the caller of `fib`. The raise of the exception is sort of a red herring to your question--it doesn't serve any useful purpose in this example other than as a demonstration of the behavior of `retry`.

Ruby's `retry` is similar to other control keywords like `next` and `break`, and `redo`. The `redo` keyword means to retry the current loop or block from the top. The `retry` keyword works inside a rescue to retry the current block that threw the exception.

So what happens here is some initial values are set for `i`, `n`, and `result`, a base case is checked (`i == -1`), and if not satisfied, we update the values and retry from the top. Notice that since these values are method parameters and not local variables, they are not reinitialized.

Careful, since Fibonacci is a very common example (and a very poor one) of recursion, not to mistake this for a recursive algorithm. The `RunAgain` raise and rescue functions like a loop, without re-calling the function or modifying the callstack.

Your example code is equivalent to

```
def fib(i)
  n, result = 1, 0
  (i+1).times { n, result = n + result, n }
  result
end
```

Note in both cases, `i` is just a counter and nothing more. We run the code `i+1` times. Note also the typical need for a temporary variable to swap values is replaced by ruby's multiple assignment construct.

Comment: If I am asking for fibonacci for a large value then there will be 10 million exceptions raised. If all those exceptions information is kept on stack then stack trace error will be thrown eventually. Hence my question was is the stack trace information removed from stack when next exception comes along.

Comment: @Nadal, see the second sentence of my response. "There are two entries on the stack the entire time." Your example has zero recursion, and the raised exceptions do not have any impact on the stack.